# How can I move container indicator back to bottom of the tab in Firefox 89

Tags: firefox

After upgrading Firefox to version 89 on Windows 10, the multi-account container indicator on tabs moved to top of the tab (it is this purple bar) - see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edUsa.png)

Previously it was at the bottom of tabs. Is there any setting that would move the indicator back to the bottom of the tab? Disabling proton didn't change this.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with Mozilla's corporate shenanigans that follows the current trends of over-dumbing things down (Google started this !) just for the sake of changing, then wondering why their market share drops even faster: Proton

To disable Proton, just type `about:config` in your address bar then look for the `browser.proton.enabled` then set it to `false`.

More fixes for Firefox 89 here: https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/npdb3p/firefox_890_release_proton_ui_lets_help_each/?sort=top&limit=500

Answer (score 0):

Before Firefox 113, this used to work:

`.tab-background { -moz-box-direction: reverse }`

However with 113's updates to CSS, you must now put

```
.tab-background {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

in your userChrome.css (located in `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/*.default-release/chrome/userChrome.css`, at least on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Using Firefox 115 I had to adjust the other answer like this:

```
#sidebar-box {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```