# How to switch back to Firefox' old style of tabs?

Tags: firefox, tabs, border, ux

The recent update (89 I think) causes all tabs to render in the same continuous shading, which makes it somehow more difficult to spot each tab's start and end (regardless of the favicon, I'm sorry, silly old proper borders just were easier on my eyes). How do I get that back? I tried [this related answer's](https://superuser.com/a/1653291/35237) `browser.proton.enabled=false` to no avail, and [re-enabling compact mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/compact-mode-workaround-firefox) also did only partially restore the previous look and feel. How can I get good old tab shading and borders back?

Comment: Oddly enough, that proton toggle _did_ work for me...  And yes, FF89.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Curious - did you restart Firefox or did it work directly? Anyway, the Lepton fix I found also adds back menu icons etc, so it's not bad for me

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Are we both talking about the missing `|` separators between tabs? Maybe you were irritated by something else than I am 

Comment: I also just learned the `browser.proton.enabled`-fix will likely not work anymore with FF90: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1709425#c2 **edit** [make that 91](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1709425#c7)

Comment: I was referring to _both_ the missing separators _and_ the color being so uniform. I flipped that switch in the config, and got back my dark tabs for unselected, and they were separated with a thin line.

Comment: I just turned off auto updates and will probably never leave FF89 with `browser.proton.enabled=false`. Mozilla can no longer be trusted with the future of their own product.

Comment: Well dang, FF92 broke the vestigial `browser.proton.enabled=false` support that at least kept the titlebar tab colors matched to the Windows 10 accent color :(

Comment: @genpfault It's still possible to get them back with userChrome.css: https://matthewminer.name/blog/how-to-get-windows-accent-colors-back-in-firefox-92

Answer (score 56):

In Firefox 91, restore the old tab style as follows:

1. Open *about:config*.
2. Search for **toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets**.
3. Double-click the value to set it to `true`.
4. Open *about:support*.
5. Search for **Profile Directory** (or **Profile Folder**).
6. Click **Open Directory** (or **Open Folder**).
7. Create a directory named `chrome`.
8. Navigate into the **chrome** directory.
9. Create a new file inside **chrome** named `userChrome.css`.
10. Copy and paste the following code into **userChrome.css**:

    ```
     .tab-background {
       border-radius: 0px 0px !important;
       margin-bottom: 0px !important;
     }

     .tabbrowser-tab:not([selected=true]):not([multiselected=true]) .tab-background {
       background-color: color-mix(in srgb, currentColor 5%, transparent);
     }

     menupopup>menu,
     menupopup>menuitem {
       padding-block: 2px !important;
     }

     :root {
       --arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 2px !important;
     }
    ```
11. Save the file.
12. Restart Firefox.

The old tab style is restored.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed `5%` to `15%` for more contrast.

Comment: Is this some kind of bad taste joke? The settings page is bloated with useless options no one ever cares or needs but they failed to add a **Classic tab style** option? Who is running Firefox now, Yahoo? AOL?

Comment: Since the disconnected tab is the only thing really bothering me, to me, it suffices to change it just with `.tab-background {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: @andreszs This is like last 10-15 years trend of software: 1. poor and useless settings with a lot of security settings; 2. new versions bring useless features and remove useful features.

Comment: Any idea how to make top corners round and look like chrome?

Answer (score 13):

Not surprisingly [I'm not the only one disliking this](https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/nrf34i/why_the_old_ui_was_better_when_having_alot_of/), and fortunately there's already a fix called Lepton at https://github.com/black7375/Firefox-UI-Fix#installation-guide. It still doesn't feel 100% proper, but so much better already with simple tab separators.

Answer (score 5):

My version of `userChrome.css`, where I changed only the part that bothers me (detached tabs).

- Tabs are attached to the toolbar, except when a background tab is multi-selected.
- The tab has the same color as the toolbar when selected.

```css
.tab-background {
  border-radius: var(--tab-border-radius) var(--tab-border-radius) 0 0 !important;
  margin-top: 1px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 31px !important;
}
.tabbrowser-tab[multiselected=true]:not([selected=true]) .tab-background {
  border-radius: var(--tab-border-radius) !important;
  margin-top: 2px !important;
  margin-bottom: 1px !important;
  padding-bottom: 29px !important;
}
.tabbrowser-tab[selected=true] .tab-background ,
.tabbrowser-tab[multiselected=true] .tab-background {
  background-color: var(--toolbar-bgcolor) !important;
  background-image: var(--toolbar-bgimage) !important;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of variables, rather than hard-coded values.

Comment: Where are variable values?

Answer (score 2):

Using [userChrome.css](https://www.howtogeek.com/334716/how-to-customize-firefoxs-user-interface-with-userchrome.css/). you can easily customize many aspects of Firefox. In the example below, inactive tabs are uniformly gray, the active tab is a gradient ascending from red to green, and the tab over which the cursor hovers is a gradient from light to dark gray.

[image: Firefox tab appearance change]

- Open your [Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data).

  - In Linux, `Home\.mozilla\firefox\xxxxxxxx.default`
  - In Windows,  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxxxx.default`
  - Mac OS, `Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default`.
- If there is no folder *Chrome*, create it.
- If there is no file *userChrome.css* in that folder, create it as a text document, i.e. with *Notepad*, *Notepad++*, or other text editor.
- Copy and paste text below and save the file. (If you're editing an existing *userChrome.css* and the `@namespace` line exists, there's no need to duplicate it.)
- Close and restart Firefox to see the new tab style.

  ```
  @namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

  /* Tab: selected colors */
  #tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab[selected] .tab-content { background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#AAFFAA,#FFAAFF) !important; }

  /* Tab: hovered colors */
  #tabbrowser-tabs .tabbrowser-tab:hover:not([selected]) .tab-content { background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#808080,#FFFFFF) !important; }
  ```

Feel free to modify the appearance to your taste. The style sheet code is easy to understand by inspection, and mistakes do no harm - just remove them and restart Firefox. See [Mozilla here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1231277) and [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1282095), for example, on tab coloring.

Comment: Those still look awful

Comment: @StevenPenny, Chacun à son goût. However, if you don't like the appearance, **read the answer** to make them fit your taste.

Comment: ***This is my favorite answer!*** It is very simple to adjust to one's system color. For example, I was able to fit this to Linux Plasma Dark look by changing the color. I have a question: given that the `background: linear-gradient` settings gives a nice liquid but different look than what I want in Plasma, is there other variable instead of `linear-gradient` that I could use so that colors are distributed [like this](https://i.imgur.com/QoBT8Sh.png)?

Comment: [How to change my userChrome.css to get Firefox tabs similar to the buttons of KDE Plasma Dark Task Manager?](https://superuser.com/q/1765917/1039759)

Answer (score 0):

This post and the first answer are a *great* starting point, but said first answer has the tab background not exactly the same color as the toolbar beneath it and it was irritating me, so i dug a little more and this is what i came up with (***works only for Linux***, on windows Firefox is themed slightly different, i'll update this post with a windows version upon request):

[image]

```css
/* 
about:config -> toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets -> true
create <user-profile-dir>/chrome/userChrome.css and insert:
*/

.tabbrowser-tab .tab-background {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1px color-mix(in srgb, currentColor 40%, transparent), 0 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset !important;
  background-image: var(--toolbar-non-lwt-bgimage) !important;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.tabbrowser-tab:not([selected=true]):not([multiselected=true]) .tab-background {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}

.tab-close-button:hover {
   background-color: color-mix(in srgb, #000000 15%, transparent) !important;
   color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.tabbrowser-tab:not([selected=true]):not([multiselected=true]) .tab-close-button:hover {
   background-color: color-mix(in srgb, #000000 10%, transparent) !important;
}

menupopup>menu,
menupopup>menuitem {
  padding-block: 5px !important;
}

:root {
  --arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 5px !important;
}

.browser-toolbar {background-color: none !important;}
#navigator-toolbox-background {--toolbar-bgimage: var(--toolbar-non-lwt-bgimage) !important}
```